# A little help with this picture

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

[image: alien world image]

https://www.deviantart.com/abiogenisis/art/Xenobiology-42223053v

So currently I’m working on little project on mine, more specifically world building, and just so happens that this is image is my main inspiration and I will like to expand it. So before the question, ideally my world would be smaller than Earth size, not a lot of flora and the creatures here huge(bigger than humans). So my question is from this image is, what is this world made of, like atmosphere, temperature, what the liquid is made of, are the creatures can be other than carbon based?

Comment: If you don't know that much about chemistry and meteorology and so on, do you really think that any of these parameters truly influence your world? Why does it matter if those creatures do use the chemical element "carbon"? Do you want to go someplace with this idea? If so, elaborate, or we can't help you. Fight the battles you can win. If you don't have any background or knowledge in science, it's very hard to pull any of these off

Comment: It is good form to credit images you post.

Comment: Fair enough, now I don’t remember when I got this but it was in the google images. Now as for elaboration, I guess what I’m trying to ask is it possible for example the liquid their is not water but other solvent, cause I know that having liquid surface is only possible if the world lies within the habitable zone of the star but I know that even if it wasn’t in the zone, other types of liquid could exist. That is why I came here to ask because I’m very interested in the science of everything so I apologize if I offended anyone by my lack of knowledge

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the original source is https://www.deviantart.com/abiogenisis/art/Xenobiology-42223053

Comment: The work of art is copyrighted by user [Abiogenesis](https://www.deviantart.com/abiogenisis) of [DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/). Publishing this work without a license from the copyright holder is illegal. Do you or don't you have a license to publish this work?

Comment: Hard to determine exactly what is going on in the picutre but to hazard a guess it is the Moon of a gas giant and the liquid is methane

Answer (score 1):

this is too broad for this site and will likely be removed, but this is exactly my type of thing so here we go.

size of planet and gravity:

It looks like a moon (see a gas giant in the background), and therefore probably has lower gravity than the earth, since it is smaller.

atmosphere and liquid:

The atmosphere seems pretty similar to ours since the sky is blue, and there appear to be water clouds. the astronaut is wearing a space suit. this could be because there is a gas poisonous to humans in the air, or alternatively that the air is much less dense. if there is a less dense atmosphere then it would be harder for the life form to be large. for that reason, it is likely that there is something dangerous in the air.  if the atmosphere is the same composition then it is likely water that you see.

lifeforms:

this means that these creatures likely have a similar composition to our terran life. they may be larger than our life forms because of one main reason. one possibility is the low gravity of this moon. that would allow species to grow without as high requirements. for weight. the formations in the background may be organic. they could be a lichen-like coral thing, which is formed of layers and layers of lichen thing forming a rocky shell.

hope this helps. when asking questions here ask more specific things such as what is the chemical composition of... or what kind of material was accessible in the nth century which can... for things like the question you just posted maybe ask it on Reddit on r/worldbuilding or r/speculativeevolution.

Comment: Could be $CO_2$ clouds; the ground appears to be frozen over. That fits with the small moon guess, as the comparatively thinner atmosphere allows a lot more heat to be lost to space

Comment: yeah, and that could be why it is dangerous for humans to go outside, because of the cold and the CO2